# What is the largest perennial herbaceous plant?

Tags: botany

What is the largest perennial herbaceous plant? My guess would be some kind of banana or bamboo.

Comment: That would be the banana. That being said, I seem to have a hard time finding a record of where the largest banana *plant* was found (but lots of records for largest fruits)...

Comment: This sounds like another homework question.

Comment: Is the [tag:taxonomy] tag appropriate here?

Comment: It is not homework. Question about facts aren't necessarily homework. Please don't be biased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tallest banana species is Musa Ingens (15m) which grows in the forest of Papua New Guinea and Indonesia. It also claimed as the the world's largest herbaceous plant. http://www.thestatworld.com/2015/12/musa-ingens-the-tallest-banana-plant-in-world.html

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned above, the largest perennial herbaceous plant is indeed the banana.  Whilst the main reference to this ("Yes, we have more bananas" - an article in the Royal Horticultural Society Journal from May 2002) has been removed from their website it would be I'm sure possible to order should you need to.

This [summary of the banana](http://www.scribd.com/arun_raja/d/48202430-Banana-files) mentions that the pseudo-stem of the banana plant grows to 6-7.6m in height - I haven't found anything taller when looking around so it doesn't generate any reason to doubt the removed article.

Regarding the comments on Bamboo, there are 7 genera containing bamboo species.  All of these ([Arthrostylidium Rupr](http://delta-intkey.com/grass/www/arthrost.htm), [Bambusa Schreb](http://herbarium.usu.edu/webmanual/info2.asp?name=Bambusa&type=treatment), [Chusquea Kunth](http://delta-intkey.com/grass/www/chusquea.htm), [Dendrocalamus Nees](http://www.inbar.int/publication/txt/tr17/Dendrocalamus/DE-r.htm), [Phyllostachys Siebold & Zucc.](http://delta-intkey.com/grass/www/phyllost.htm), [Pseudosasa Makino](http://delta-intkey.com/grass/www/p_sasa.htm) and [Sasa Makino & Shibata](http://delta-intkey.com/grass/www/sasa.htm)) are described as having persistent woody stems so don't meet your herbaceous requirement.

Comment: So what happens with bamboo? Doesn't it grow a lot taller than 6 meters sometimes? It's also perennial and herbaceous, right?

Comment: Not all bamboo species are herbaceous, some are woody. I'll dig into the relative sizes of the two variants some more tomorrow =)

Comment: @Problemaniac I've done the research and it seems I was mistaken last night.  All genera with common name bamboo in ITIS are woody as shown in my now revised answer =)

Comment: So was it a common misunderstanding that "a bamboo forest is/can be just one big tall grass of a kind"?

Comment: It would seem to be - I would imagine that confusion stems (no pun intended) from all bamboo species being contained within the Family  Poaceae, which has a common name of 'grasses'.  However the distinction between herbaceous and woody happens lower down at Genus.

Comment: It's not a misunderstanding or confusion - all bamboos are grasses.  Grasses are defined as the graminoids, which includes Poaceae (the true grasses, including bamboo), plus the Cyperaceae (sedges) and Juncaceae (rushes). So it is perfectly accurate to call a bamboo forest a forest of tall grass.

Comment: @RoryM: the link to 'summary of the banana' is dead now.